# Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy, libc6 breaks after update. How to recover half-installed libc6

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

After an update my libc6 broke, in particular `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` was deleted. I had to boot from a live distro to copy it back because no command was working anymore (now I have learnt the lesson, so I am keeping a root shell open so that I can copy it back using busybox without rebooting).

Every time I try to do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` the same problem occur and I need to restore the ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 file.
I have tried different things:

- `sudo apt install -f`
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- `sudo apt autoclean`
- `sudo apt clean`
- deleted the file `/var/lib/dpkg/status`

but nothing worked, the same issue keeps occurring.

Libc6 version installed is 2.35-0ubuntu3 but it claims that 2.35-0ubuntu3.3 is to be installed. The command `dpkg -l` at the moment yields this:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name              Version               Architecture Description
+++-=================-=====================-============-===============================================
ii  gcc-12-base:amd64 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
iHR libc6:amd64       2.35-0ubuntu3.3       amd64        (no description available)
iU  libcrypt1:amd64   1:4.4.27-1            amd64        libcrypt shared library
```

Package libc6:amd64 is half-installed and needs to be reinstalled. The strange thing is that there is no description available.

The output of `sudo apt upgrade` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The list of packages with unmet dependencies is empty. Launching `sudo apt --fix-broken install` ends in error and the file `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` gets deleted.

The output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcrypt1:amd64:
 libcrypt1:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.25); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libcrypt1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcrypt1:amd64
```

The output of `sudo apt update` is:

```
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                                                                                    
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease                                                                                                             
Get:3 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Alexx2000/xUbuntu_22.04  InRelease [1.529 B]                                                                                       
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease                                                                                                                            
Hit:6 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                    
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wereturtle/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                     
Hit:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/freecad-maintainers/freecad-stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                                                        
Hit:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                                                                                                        
Get:12 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_20.04 ./ InRelease [2.961 B]                                                                                                                   
Hit:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:14 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:15 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                           
Ign:16 http://gmusicbrowser.org/deb ./ InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:17 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                               
Get:18 http://gmusicbrowser.org/deb ./ Release [1.722 B]                                                                     
Hit:19 https://paulcarroty.gitlab.io/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/debs vscodium InRelease                                                       
Hit:20 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                         
Hit:22 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/spvkgn/deadbeef/ubuntu jammy InRelease                           
Hit:21 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease                                         
Fetched 6.212 B in 4s (1.511 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

and `apt list --upgradable` shows:

```
Listing... Done
libc6/jammy-updates 2.35-0ubuntu3.3 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.35-0ubuntu3.3]
N: There are 4 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

I searched the web for a solution and tried some other things to no avail and I don't know what to do now.

How can I restore libc6 to a healthy state?

Comment: Please add `sudo apt update` to your question.

Comment: @nobody I updated my question

Comment: Please I need the whole output; to check if all ubuntu sources are active on your system.

Comment: @nobody updated.

Comment: Oh my heavens. Debian, ubuntu, opensuse. That may be the worst sources list ever posted here.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I use those sources only for specific packages

Comment: Please backup your personal data and install jammy anew. This to repair is a long way to go.

Comment: @nobody would you at least show me the way?

Comment: The problem is not only debian sources also some ppa's. And you can not install new software like `ppa-purge` nor `apt-show-versions`

Comment: If you can run synaptic you can use the Origin button in the left column to see what packages came from which of your smorgasbord of sources. But your system is probably too broken to actually fix anything.

Comment: @nobody I have ppa-purge installed however

Comment: I'm afraid the easiest way is to restore from backup